# IE9: Logging jQuery objects

Tags: internet-explorer-9, jquery

In Google Chrome, when logging a jQuery object, the console shows an array with the various DOM elements inside. I can even hover over the DOM elements in the console, and they appear highlighted in the browser window.

In IE9, when logging a jQuery element I simply get `[object Object]`.

How can I get IE9 to be more helpful when logging jQuery objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not ideal, but more helpful than built in function

```
var obj = $("div#myTestDIV");

log(obj);

function log(o, level)
{
    level = level || 1;
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < level; i++)
    {
        str += '  ';
    }

    for (var p in o)
    {
        if (typeof o[p] == 'function')
        {
            try
            {
                console.log(str + p + ": " + o[p]());
            }
            catch(e){}
        }
        else if (typeof o[p] == 'object')
        {
            log(o[p], level + 1)
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                console.log(str + p + ": " + o[p]);
            }
            catch(e){}
        }
    }

}
```